# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'learning_logsdjango'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to run this command: `python manage.py makemigrations learning_logs`; but, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'learning_logsdjango'
```

These are the additions I've made to these two files; I'm using the Crash Course Python book by Eric Matthes--currently on page 386.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text
```

**settings.py**

```
--snip--
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        # My apps
        'learning_logs'
   # Default django apps.
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
--snip--
```

Comment: try to add a comma after `'learning_logs'` in `INSTALLED_APPS` and make sure you have only 4 spaces before the start `'learning_logs'`.

Comment: after that just enter `python manage.py makemigrations`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- add comma `,` after 'learning_logs' app name

```
--snip--
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   # My apps
   'learning_logs',
   # Default django apps.
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: oh god i'm so stupid, thank you so much